# Is there a proper way to download a container image from Artifactory with the jfrog CLI for docker pull?

Tags: docker, artifactory, jfrog-cli

I'm trying to transfer a container between instances of Artifactory. Performing:

```
jfrog rt dl my-images-repo repository/ --url="http://localhost/artifactory" --user=user --password=pass --recursive
```

then:

```
jfrog rt u repository/ new-images-repo --url="http://localhost/artifactory" --user=user --password=pass --flat=false
```

finally:

```
docker pull new-images-repo/my-image
```

yields:
missing signature key

However doing the same process via the GUI and exporting the folder and then re-importing it seems to transfer the containers fine. Investigating this it seems that the container "properties" files aren't being downloaded/uploaded when I run those jfrog rt u/dl commands.

Anybody have an idea?

Thanks

Comment: Since there isn't a way to automatically store the properties of a file after it is downloaded, the only idea that I can think of right now is to create a script that queries the properties on the source Artifactory server using the "jfrog rt s" command, reading the output using the "jq" tool, and then using "jfrog rt u" with the --props flag to set the props on the target server. Definitely not a trivial solution. If you actually manage to do this, would be awesome to post the script here. You"ll get my thumbs up for sure!

Comment: I ended up doing this except leveraging the python artifactory api wrapper "rtpy". Sorry I can't open source the code or else I would. Its pretty straightforward tho - basically exactly what you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Artifactory Pro (or SaaS, Enterprise, E+) then you can use [Repository Replication](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Repository+Replication) in order to achieve the transfer of Docker of images from one instance to another

The other problem is that we are using `jfrog rt dl` and `jfrog rt u` which are both generic upload/download commands and will work perhaps for other repo types.

Docker has a specific API so you will need to use either the Docker client or the JFrog CLI's push/pull.

In general what you will want to do is:

`docker pull SOURCE_IMAGE[:TAG]`

`docker tag SOURCE_IMAGE[:TAG] TARGET_IMAGE[:TAG]`

`docker push TARGET_IMAGE[:TAG]`

Lastly there is also [system/repository export/import](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Import+and+Export) which can do just what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have Artifactory pro with replication you still have 2 more options.

On target Artifactory you can use a docker remote repository that will be connected to the source Artifactory repository.
By running docker pull command on this remote repository you will populate the local cache of your target Artifactory making it available locally.

Optionnaly you can then run the promote REST API endpoint to move your image from the cache to a local repository.
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-PromoteDockerImage

The second approach, if you want to use the cli would be to use it as a wrapper of docker client (very similar to Angellio approach but taking benefits of the cli for authentication)

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-BuildingDockerImages

Commands would be

```
jfrog rt dpl ...

docker tag

jfrog rt dp ...
```

As a side note, one of the main difference is amount of hop, with first approach there is only one "movement" of the image and it might be something to consider in conjunction with the amount/volume of images you want to transfer and also how ften you want to proceed.